# PHP Passing image from HTML form errors

Tags: php, file-upload

Planning a basic image up load to start, not done it before. Having a problem with the form not passing the picture to the PHP file.
The errors i am recieving are;

> Notice: Undefined index: file in
>   C:\Users\PC\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\php\addpic.php on line 2 Notice:
>   Undefined index: file in
>   C:\Users\PC\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\php\addpic.php on line 8 Notice:
>   Undefined index: file in
>   C:\Users\PC\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\php\addpic.php on line 9 Notice:
>   Undefined index: file in
>   C:\Users\PC\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\php\addpic.php on line 10 Notice:
>   Undefined index: file in
>   C:\Users\PC\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\php\addpic.php on line 11

HTML form

```
<div id="addpicdialog" title="Change Pic">
<p>Please Fill in out member information.</p>
<form name="changepic" method="POST" action="php/addpic.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>" >
<p>DISPLAY CURRENT PIC HERE</p>

<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"  /> 
</form>
</div>
```

addpic.php

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
}
?>
```

Comment: have you actually sent any data to the websit when you receive the error? and you should also add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploads requires `multipart/form-data`

Try this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="changepic" method="POST" action="php/addpic.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>" >
```

Tip:

Use `isset(...)`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
 <form name="changepic" method="POST" action="php/addpic.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>" >
```

By:

```
 <form name="changepic" method="POST" action="php/addpic.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```